How to update JSON columns in FastAPI
I am trying to set the value for a key in a json stored on a column in the database (MySql).
Sample Code:
import json
from sqlmodel import Field, JSON
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from settings import settings
from typing import Annotated
from sqlmodel import Session, create_engine, SQLModel
from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI


class Organization(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "organizations"
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Field()
    meta: dict = Field(sa_type=JSON)


class MyService:

    def __init__(self, session: Session):
        self.session = session

    def update(self, value: str, organization_id: str):
        organization = self.session.get(Organization, organization_id)
        print(organization)
        organization.meta['custom_key'] = value
        self.session.add(organization)
        self.session.commit()


def get_session():
    with Session(engine) as session:
        yield session


engine = create_engine(settings.db_connection_string, echo=True)
SessionDep = Annotated[Session, Depends(get_session)]


app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=settings.cors_origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)


@app.on_event("startup")
def on_startup():
    SQLModel.metadata.create_all(engine)


@app.post("/update/{organization_id}")
def update(organization_id: str, value: str, session: SessionDep):
    service = MyService(session)
    service.update(value, organization_id)
    return {"message": "success"}

The organization is read correctly from the database and the value of meta is correct. But I don't see any update statements run when I hit the update function.
Logs:
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [28024] using WatchFiles
INFO:     Started server process [39612]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
2024-10-15 15:03:16,139 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2024-10-15 15:03:16,140 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-10-15 15:03:16,141 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@sql_mode
2024-10-15 15:03:16,141 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-10-15 15:03:16,142 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@lower_case_table_names
2024-10-15 15:03:16,142 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-10-15 15:03:16,143 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-10-15 15:03:16,143 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine DESCRIBE `kraya_local`.`organizations`
2024-10-15 15:03:16,144 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-10-15 15:03:16,146 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
INFO:     Application startup complete.
2024-10-15 15:03:18,441 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-10-15 15:03:18,444 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT organizations.id AS organizations_id, organizations.name AS organizations_name, organizations.meta AS organizations_meta 
FROM organizations 
WHERE organizations.id = %(pk_1)s
2024-10-15 15:03:18,444 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00030s] {'pk_1': '9befc383-4db8-413e-934a-2e2f6dce51ed'}
name='Tripper Trails' meta={'custom_key': 'test'} id='9befc383-4db8-413e-934a-2e2f6dce51ed'
2024-10-15 15:03:18,457 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
INFO:     127.0.0.1:52204 - "POST /update/9befc383-4db8-413e-934a-2e2f6dce51ed?value=test HTTP/1.1" 200 OK


Alternatively, if I set the model as
class Organization(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "organizations"
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Field()
    meta: str = Field()

and do this in the function:

def update(self, value: str, organization_id: str):
    organization = self.session.get(Organization, organization_id)
    print(organization)

    # organization.meta['custom_key'] = value

    organization_metadata = json.loads(organization.meta)
    organization_metadata['custom_key'] = value
    organization.meta = json.dumps(organization_metadata)

    self.session.add(organization)
    self.session.commit()

For this, I can see the update statement run in the logs
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8001 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [20320] using WatchFiles
INFO:     Started server process [23168]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
2024-10-15 15:05:50,857 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT DATABASE()
2024-10-15 15:05:50,857 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-10-15 15:05:50,858 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@sql_mode
2024-10-15 15:05:50,858 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-10-15 15:05:50,859 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT @@lower_case_table_names
2024-10-15 15:05:50,859 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-10-15 15:05:50,860 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-10-15 15:05:50,861 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine DESCRIBE `kraya_local`.`organizations`
2024-10-15 15:05:50,861 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [raw sql] {}
2024-10-15 15:05:50,877 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
INFO:     Application startup complete.
2024-10-15 15:05:54,774 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2024-10-15 15:05:54,778 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT organizations.id AS organizations_id, organizations.name AS organizations_name, organizations.meta AS organizations_meta 
FROM organizations 
WHERE organizations.id = %(pk_1)s
2024-10-15 15:05:54,779 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00082s] {'pk_1': '9befc383-4db8-413e-934a-2e2f6dce51ed'}
name='Tripper Trails' meta='{}' id='9befc383-4db8-413e-934a-2e2f6dce51ed'
2024-10-15 15:05:54,784 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine UPDATE organizations SET meta=%(meta)s WHERE organizations.id = %(organizations_id)s
2024-10-15 15:05:54,785 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00078s] {'meta': '{"custom_key": "test"}', 'organizations_id': '9befc383-4db8-413e-934a-2e2f6dce51ed'}
2024-10-15 15:05:54,790 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
INFO:     127.0.0.1:52267 - "POST /update/9befc383-4db8-413e-934a-2e2f6dce51ed?value=test HTTP/1.1" 200 OK


I needed to set the JSON column as a mutable.
the updated model would be:
class Organization(SQLModel, table=True):
    __tablename__ = "organizations"
    id: int | None = Field(default=None, primary_key=True)
    name: str = Field()
    meta: dict = Field(sa_type=MutableDict.as_mutable(JSON))

ref: section on "Detecting Changes in JSON columns when using the ORM" in the sqlalchemy docs
